# issue with page numbering - roman and arabic

Tags: page-numbering, roman-numerals

I use "report" as a document class. I would like to have both numberings in my document, roman and Arabic, so I included the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 % \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
 % \@mainmatterfalse
   }

\makeatother

\usepackage{subfiles} 


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ Declaration of authorship}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ Acknowledgements}


\maketitle

\chapter*{Declaration of authorship}

some text....

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

some text....

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\include{chapter 1}
\include[chapter 2}
and so on....

\end{document}
```

however, that prints out the page numbers only on the first and sometimes the second page of each chapter...
what is missing?

update:

[image: Declaration of authorship oage number]

followed by a numberless blank page

then

[image: Acknowledgements page number]

and this is how numbering goes throughout the whole document.

Comment: Please expand your question to add figures  or make a comment.

Comment: @SimonDispa
done, please see the updates in the post

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use `book` than `report` because the former "understands" `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, so page numbering will work fine without additional code. (The commands you are using are part of the class `book`).

Some dummy text was added to check the page numbering.

[image: x]

[image: y]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY  dummy text <<<<<

\title{Great title}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle

\frontmatter    

\chapter*{Declaration of authorship}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ Declaration of authorship} % put after chapter* <<<<<<
\kant[1-5]

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ Acknowledgements}% put after chapter* <<<<<<
\kant[1-5]

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{ONE}
\kant[1-5]

\chapter{TWO}
\kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Your code also works fine when adding some dummy text.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
    
\makeatletter   
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage    
    \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
    \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
    \else
    \clearpage
    \fi
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY  dummy text <<<<<

\title{Great title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \frontmatter        
    
    \chapter*{Declaration of authorship}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ Declaration of authorship} % put after chapter* <<<<<<
    \kant[1-5]
    
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ Acknowledgements}% put after chapter* <<<<<<
    \kant[1-5]
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{ONE}
    \kant[1-5]
    
    \chapter{TWO}
    \kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: i tried the solution with the book document class
and still the issue remains, please see the post again, I added figures

Comment: @sphero -- "still the issue remain". *Which*  issue? Please elaborate.

Comment: +1. In the code block with the `book` document class, if you replace both instances of `\chapter*{...}` with `\chapter{...}`, you can get rid of both `\addcontentsline` directives.

Comment: @Mico They are part of the OP question.

Comment: @sphero I updated the `book` code. Run it as is and check that all pages are numbered correctly.

Comment: @Mico, my wish was not to include these two chapters in the toc, but it is fine, adding or removing them do no good to the main problem

Comment: @SimonDispa
well, the only update i see in your answer is that you added "oneside" to the document class, I did that, and still the same issue remains - the page numbers are in the toc, but are not printed on each page